# C# creating a method valid only for arrays of my class

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say that I have a class `foo` and another `bar`. I want to create a method in the `foo` class to convert a `foo` array to a `bar` object (that is not an array), like this:

```
foo[] v1 = new foo[] { };
bar v2 = v1.ToBar();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [**Extension Method**:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic, there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

All you need is a public static class to hold your extension method. Notice `this` before first method parameter - that's what makes it an extension method.

```
public static class FooExtensions
{ 
    public static Bar ToBar(this Foo[] source)
    {
        return new Bar();  // replace with correct logic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I can use a static method, but I wanted to know if I could do it in a more "elegant" way

Comment: Because it's an extension method, you can run it via `v1.ToBar();`

Comment: **Extension** method is the best you can get.

Comment: @MauroF. You can shorten it to simple assignment by use of [custom implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) ([Example with array](https://ideone.com/nr1HfD)). However, in most cases, it will worsen readability of code (implicity and readability tend to dislike).

Comment: sorry, I didn't even know what extension method was, thanks for clearing up